# and logical operation on python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, bitwise-operators, logical-operators

I use python 2.7.12 on Ubuntu 16.04, I have this in some part of my code:

```
for i in np.arange(0,max+1):
    ...
    if i != 1 and i != max :
            t_try[i] = (C_[i])/(2.0*D)
```

but I get different results with this changes:

```
for i in np.arange(0,max+1):
    ...
    if (i != 1) and (i != max) :
            t_try[i] = (C_[i])/(2.0*D)
```

or

```
for i in np.arange(0,max+1):
    ...
    if (i != 1 and i != max) :
            t_try[i] = (C_[i])/(2.0*D)
```

I failed to see what is the problem.

**update:** please note I'm not talking about "Boolean operators" and  "Bitwise operators" accepted answer is @fernand 's answer, BTW thanks for you valuable time

Comment: Can you explain what you try to achieve and what is the expected output? Do you need a logical and (`and`) or a bitwise `&` (which might be the same in your case since it seems you are doing bitwise on boolean...)? The bitwise `&` has higher priority than `!=` and `and` which means it is applied first - based on http://www.mathcs.emory.edu/~valerie/courses/fall10/155/resources/op_precedence.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is for the precedence of operators: 
https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html
or, and are prevalent over ==, =!

Answer (score 0):

In `python`, `&` is not a logical conjunction, but rather a bit-wise AND operator. Try changing `&` to `and` in your examples.